# Windows media foundation decoding audio streams

Tags: python, windows, audio, decode, ms-media-foundation

I am new to Windows Media Foundation, I am currently following some tutorials on the basics to get started and decoding audio. However, I am running int a few issues. Using: Windows 10 64bit (1809), and am using Python (ctypes and COM's to interface).

1) The `IMFSourceReader` will not allow me to select or deselect any stream out. I have tried wav and mp3 formats (and multiple different files), but they all error out. According to the docs, to speed up performance you want to deselect other streams and select the stream you want, in this case, audio.

However:
`source_reader.SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM, False)`

Produces an error:
`OSError: [WinError -1072875853] The stream number provided was invalid.`

Which should be correct since `MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM` value (DWORD of 4294967294) should be universal? Or am I incorrect in that?

I've tried seeing if I could just select the audio stream:
`source_reader.SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, True)`

Which produces a different error:
`OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000001`

My current code up until that point:

```
MFStartup(MF_VERSION)  # initialize

source_reader = IMFSourceReader() 

filename = "C:\\test.mp3"

MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(filename, None, ctypes.byref(source_reader))  # out: source reader.

if source_reader:  # Not null
    source_reader.SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM, False)  # invalid stream #?

    source_reader.SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, True)  # access violation??
```

`IMFSourceReader` seems to be functioning just fine for other functions, Such as `GetCurrentMediaType`, `SetCurrentMediaType`, etc. Could it still return `IMFSourceReader` if there are any issues?

2) I am not sure if not being able to select the streams is causing further issues (I suspect it is). If I just skip selecting or deselecting streams, everything actually works up until trying to convert a sample into a single buffer with `ConvertToContiguousBuffer`, which, according to the docs, outputs into a `IMFMediaBuffer`. The problem is, after running that, it does return as `S_OK`, but the buffer is `null`. I used `GetBufferCount` to make sure there are some buffers in the sample atleast, and it always returns 1-3 depending on the file used, so it shouldn't be empty.

Here is the relevant code:

```
while True:
    flags = DWORD()
    sample = IMFSample()

    source_reader.ReadSample(streamIndex, 0, None, ctypes.byref(flags), None, ctypes.byref(sample))  # flags, sample [out]

    if flags.value & MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM:
        print("READ ALL OF STREAM")
        break

    if sample:
        buffer_count = DWORD()
        sample.GetBufferCount(ctypes.byref(buffer_count))
        print("BUFFER COUNT IN SAMPLE", buffer_count.value)
    else:
        print("NO SAMPLE")
        continue

    buffer = IMFMediaBuffer()
    hr = sample.ConvertToContiguousBuffer(ctypes.byref(buffer))

    print("Conversion succeeded", hr == 0)  # true

    if buffer:
        print("CREATED BUFFER")
    else:
        print("BUFFER IS NULL")
        break
```

I am unsure where to go from here, I couldn't find much explanations on the internet regarding these specific issues. Is WMF still the goto for Windows 10? Should I be using something else? I really am stumped and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think `SetStreamSelection` is fine, maybe Python bindings for this method are broken.

Comment: This was correct, in Python com's you have to have the exact order of the methods listed in the header files or it will not work. They were not lined up correctly, and some methods are removed/added depending on the version. Once I squared that away, it started working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS` instead of `MF_SOURCE_READER_ANY_STREAM`.

```
source_reader.SetStreamSelection(MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS, False)
```

When reading the samples you also need to specify a valid stream index which in your case I suspect `0` isn't. Try:

```
source_reader.ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, 0, None, ctypes.byref(flags), None, ctypes.byref(sample))
```

Also does your Python wrapper return a result when you make your Media Foundation calls? Nearly all Media Foundation methods return a `HRESULT` and it's important to check it equals `S_OK` before proceeding. If you don't it's very hard to work out where a wrong call occurred.

> Is WMF still the goto for Windows 10?

Many people have asked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539683/what-is-the-status-of-microsoft-media-foundation). The answer depends on what you need to do (in your case audio codec support is very limited so perhaps it isn't the best option). But for things like rendering audio/video, reading/writing to media files, audio/video device capture etc. it is still the case that Media Foundation is the most up to date Microsoft supported option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried both, `MF_SOURCE_READER_ALL_STREAMS`, but no change. I was looking at the header files and they seem to be the same value or maybe the header files I have are out of date? (`0xfffffffe`).

I forgot to put that `streamIndex` is `MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM`, but no change if I put it directly. The wrapper does return `HRESULT`. `ReadSample` does return `S_OK`.

Limited support isn't too much of a problem with WMF, considering the current audio I can only load are wav files. Wasn't sure if it was superceded, but that helps.

Comment: I don't know if it will help, since it's not using your Python wrapper, but here's a C++ example of reading an mp4 file https://github.com/sipsorcery/mediafoundationsamples/blob/master/MFAudio/MFAudio.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Usually, with MediaFoundation, you need to call CoInitializeEx before MFStartup :

[Media Foundation and COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/media-foundation-and-com)

> Best Practices for Applications
>
> In Media Foundation, asynchronous processing and callbacks are handled by work queues. Work queues always have multithreaded apartment (MTA) threads, so an application will have a simpler implementation if it runs on an MTA thread as well. **Therefore, it is recommended to call CoInitializeEx with the COINIT_MULTITHREADED flag.**

[MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/win32/api/mfreadwrite/nf-mfreadwrite-mfcreatesourcereaderfromurl)

> Remarks
>
> **Call CoInitialize(Ex) and MFStartup before calling this function.**

In your code, I don't see the call to CoInitializeEx.

**EDIT**

Because you are using audio file, normally you should have only one audio stream, and index should be 0.
Try :

```
source_reader.SetStreamSelection(0, True)
```

and tell us the result.

Comment: I apologize, I should have added that into my source as well.

I did try it at one point: `CoInitializeEx(None, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)` but it made no difference.